# Wrapping async java webservice call

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, async-await

I am writing some C# code to call a SOAP based Java language web service.  When I created the internal class from the wsdl I ended up with every sync endpoint having an async version as well.  So far I've ignored these as there has not been a need for async calls.  To make a long story short - there is now a need.

Here is an example of what I've tried and the (MS) unit test to test it:

```
public class Lookups : IWebRepository
{
    private readonly WebService _ws;

    public Lookups()
    {
        _ws = WebServiceExtended.Instance.Endpoint;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Cities() => _ws.getLookupList("Cities").Select(o => o as lookup).Select(l => l.Name);
    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> CitiesAsync()
    {
        var results = await _ws.LookupAsync("Cities");
        return results.Result.Select(o => o as lookup).Select(a => a.Name);
    }
}
```

I created this Extension:

```
internal static class WebServiceAsyncExtensions
{
    internal static Task<getLookupListCompletedEventArgs> LookupAsync(this WebService ws, string lookupKey)
    {
        var taskCreateSource = CreateSource<getLookupListCompletedEventArgs>(null);
        ws.getLookupListCompleted += (sender, e) => TransferCompletion(taskCreateSource, e, () => e, null);
        ws.getLookupListAsync(lookupKey);
        return taskCreateSource.Task;
    }
    private static TaskCompletionSource<T> CreateSource<T>(object state) => new TaskCompletionSource<T>(state, TaskCreationOptions.None);
    private static void TransferCompletion<T>(TaskCompletionSource<T> taskCreateSource, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e, Func<T> getResult, Action unregisterHandler)
    {
        if (e.UserState != taskCreateSource)
            return;

        if (e.Cancelled)
            taskCreateSource.TrySetCanceled();
        else if (e.Error != null)
            taskCreateSource.TrySetException(e.Error);
        else
            taskCreateSource.TrySetResult(getResult());

        unregisterHandler?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

And the test:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Lookup_Async_Cities_Succeeds()
{
    var response = await _ws.RepositoryLookups.CitiesAsync();
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(response, typeof(IEnumerable<string>));
    Assert.IsTrue(response != null);
    Assert.IsTrue(response.Any());
}
```

Looking in the generated (wsdl) code I see this:

```
/// <remarks/>
public void getLookupListAsync(string arg0) {
    this.getLookupListAsync(arg0, null);
}

/// <remarks/>
public void getLookupListAsync(string arg0, object userState) {
    if ((this.getLookupListOperationCompleted == null)) {
        this.getLookupListOperationCompleted = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OngetLookupListOperationCompleted);
    }
    this.InvokeAsync("getLookupList", new object[] {
                arg0}, this.getLookupListOperationCompleted, userState);
}
```

The challenge I am running into is when I make the call it just spins off to la la land and never returns a response.  When I test/call the Sync version I get the expected response.  This is a web service we've been using for years and we are now extending some capabilities on the C# side of things.

Am I missing something?  Better yet; what am I missing?!

Comment: Have you tried using something like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see what goes on the wire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the JAVA Web Service does not, in this case, understand async on all endpoints.  I found 2 endpoints that are async out of all the endpoints created by Microsoft's tool in VS.  Lesson learned:  because it is defined does not mean it exists.